# desktop PC won't turn on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I've turned off my desktop PC to move it to another place in the room and now it won't turn back on.

The power supply (Thermaltake TR2 RX 450w) has a small light in the back, which is normally orange when the computer is turned off and green when it's on. Now it's orange and *blinking*. When I press the power button, nothing happens, fans do not turn, no beeps, nothing.

What does the blinking orange light mean in Thermaltake PSU? Is there a way to find out what exactly needs to be replaced?

Tried:

1. Disconnecting all peripherials from the PC and also removing extra memory/cards. No change
2. Disconnecting the motherboard from the PSU. The orange light stops flashing and becomes  normal orange light as it was before in standby mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the PSU has failed.

If you were getting power out, but the motherboard or memory had failed the fans would turn and you'd get beeps (depending on the error), but with nothing and the indicator light changing that definitely indicates the PSU.

There's a [user manual](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?C=1264&ID=1907#Tab4) on the Thermaltake site. Does that say what the lights mean?

Comment: I just looked at the user manual and it doesn't seem to mention the light at all. @unbeli may have more luck contacting Thermaltake support to ask about the lights.

Comment: @Velociraptors - beat me to it. I thought I'd post the link first then look at the file.

Comment: You beat me to posting the link, since I thought I'd look at the file first. I'm not sure why Thermaltake felt the need to post the manual as a single pdf in a zip.

Comment: ok finally it was really the PSU. too bad I've bought new MB+CPU+memory first :)

Answer (score 0):

Thermaltake's official answer to me was

> *I just spoke to our engineers and unfortunately they told me that if the indicator on the PSU is flashing there is a problem with it.*

Then we disconected the front panel of the thermaltake Mozart SX tower and voila!! Everything was working again.

Even the tech guys in Thermaltake don't know what the blinking light means

PS After extensinve testing we came to the final resolution of the front USBs short circuiting. Panel is working fine but there is no front USB.